# Symfony $form->isValid returns always true

Tags: forms, validation, entity, symfony

I have a litle problem with form validation.
The method isValid() always returns true.

Here is my code:

```
public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {

        $contact = new Contact;
        $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            return new Response('Ok', 200);
        }
}
```

The ContactType code:

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('mail')
            ->add('message')
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\Contact'
        ));
    }
}
```

And the Contact entity:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Contact
{
    /*
     * @var string
     *
     * @Asserts\NotBlank("Vous devez écrire votre nom")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 3,
     *      max = 70
     * )
     */
    protected $name;

    /*
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Ce champs ne doit pas être vide")
     * @Assert\Email(
     *      checkMX = true,
     *      message = "Cet adresse email n'est pas valide"
     * )
     */
    protected $mail;

    /*
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank( message = "Vous devez écrire un message")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 10,
     *      max = 1000,
     *      minMessage = "Votre message doit comporter au moins {{ limit }} caractères",
     *      maxMessage = "Votre message ne doit pas dépasser {{ limit }} caractères"
     * )
     */
    protected $message;
```

The code of the ajaxAction always returns a 200 Ok response even if i dont follow my validation constraints.

Have you an idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Why would you expect any other http code?

Comment: @ybert in your controller add an else statement and see what happen`if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            return new Response('Ok', 200);
        } else { return $this->handleView($this-view(['form' => $form], Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST));}`

Comment: @lolmx it is the same. method isValid() always returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in annotations in your entity class.

1. *@Asserts\NotBlank("Vous devez écrire votre nom")* need a message value
   and not Asserts if you use *Constraints as Assert*
2. And the main is that annotations start with /** and not with /*

Use this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Vous devez écrire votre nom")
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 3,
 *      max = 70
 * )
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Ce champs ne doit pas être vide")
 * @Assert\Email(
 *      checkMX = true,
 *      message = "Cet adresse email n'est pas valide"
 * )
 */
protected $mail;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Vous devez écrire un message")
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 10,
 *      max = 1000,
 *      minMessage = "Votre message doit comporter au moins {{ limit }} caractères",
 *      maxMessage = "Votre message ne doit pas dépasser {{ limit }} caractères"
 * )
 */
protected $message;
```

Comment: Oh thank you!!! It was the /** ... I dont know how I didnt see it earlier!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to retrieve any errors that pass the regular form validation:

```
if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {
    /** @var FormErrorIterator $errors */
    $errors = $form->getErrors(true);

    /** @var FormError $error */
    while ($error = $errors->current()) {
        $this->addFlash('error', $error->getMessage());
        $errors->next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check again your data, perhaps all validation conditions are fulfilled

Comment: I have checked. For example i put 2 characters in message field. It required min 10 characters but it pass throught the isValid method

Answer (score 0):

Did you explicitly enable annotations in your config?

```
# app/config/config.yml

framework:
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
```

You need to explicitly enable annotations considering that you are using the annotation method to specify your constraints: